# How do you quickly know a rational function will have an oblique asymptote?

Tags: calculus

Q1: If you have a rational function, how do you know it will have oblique asymptote?

Q2: if you have a rational function, is long division the best way to find the oblique asymptote?

Thanks!

Comment: Compute $\lim f(x) /x$, if finite and different from $0$, there is an oblique asymptote.

Comment: 1) iff $f(x)=ax+b+\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}$ with $\deg R(x)<\deg Q(x)$

Answer (score 1):

If the rational function is written as $A(x)/B(x)$, then there will be an oblique asymptote if and only if $\deg A - \deg B = 1$.